# Unable to concanate String+Variable+String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I am trying to dynamically have my javascript look for an element ID in the DOM.

I am currently using this

```
var string = "retail";
document.getElementById('markup_'+string+'_percentage').value=z.toFixed(2)+"%";
```

Where the variable **"string"**  has a value like "retail"

This I thought would give a concatenated string of "markup_retail_percentage".

However it actually gives this as an error message:

```
document.getElementById("markup_"+string+"_percentage") is null
```

I have tried also using the "." and " * " operators.

One of my html elements

```
<input type="text" id="markup_retail_percentage" size="5" name="markup_retail_percentage" value="" readonly />
```

**SOLUTION!!!!**

```
//using a new variable name to be passed to function 
function percentage(elementid)
{

    elementid = "markup_" + elementid;
    elementid = elementid + "_percentage";

document.getElementById(elementid).value = "a value";


}
```

Comment: Did you mean to miss out the underscore before `'percentage'` ?

Comment: Can you post the html code where the element has an **id** of **markup_retail_percentage**?

Comment: Do you really need stackoverflow for this ?
Just see what comes in the following alerts
alert('markup_'+ string +'_percentage');
- This means variable string is incorrect
alert(document.getElementById('markup_'+ string +'_percentage'));
- If alert 1 is fine and if alert 2 gives null, then there is no element by that ID in your document

Comment: @AdelBoutros ; solution presented . It seems it was a concatenation or variable name problem

Comment: if you had written `elementid = 'markup_' + elementid + '_percentage'` it would also have worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two^w three^w four possibilities:

1. `string` doesn't contain what you think it does
2. you should have an underscore before `percentage`.
3. the specified element really doesn't exist! (thanks @jAndy)
4. it does, but the DOM isn't ready yet (thanks @Yoshi)

Comment: 3. there is no element having that id.

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the same error even with corrected string

Comment: so concatenate the string first, and display it (`alert()`, or `console.log()` to find out what's really in it.  Then check that the element actually exists!

Comment: That would seem to rule out #2 and #3.  Please show _exactly_ how you are assigning values to `string`.  Maybe there are some extra spaces?

Comment: onchange="var string='length'; margin(string);"

Comment: I call it using onchange and pass string as a parameter to the function where the code is

Comment: I refer you to previous comment - do the concatenation separately and **SHOW IT IN YOUR DEBUGGER**.  This will probably make the error obvious.

Comment: turns out I had to do this - look at solution in questions

Comment: @loosebruce calling it `string` probably didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing an underscore ahead of percentage

`document.getElementById('markup_'+ string +'percentage')`

I think you want

`document.getElementById('markup_'+ string +'_percentage')`

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the same error even with corrected string

Comment: document.getElementById("markup_" + string + "_percentage") is null

Comment: @loosebruce do you have an element with the `id` *markup_retail_percentage*?  Or is it a `class`?  Or non-existent

Comment: <input type="text" id="markup_retail_percentage" size="5" name="markup_retail_percentage" value="" readonly />

Comment: Could have something to do with the use of the word `string` as the variable name.  `String`, while not restricted, is a "predefined word".  Try changing the variable name to something else.

Comment: Turns out this was a concatenation or variable name problem? - solved it though, but thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code before the `Document` has finished loading, your markup will not have been fully parsed and the `Element` with that id will not be accessible using DOM methods.

Comment: My script loads at the end of the html page, it seems to me the problem was the variable name or how I was concatenating.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think double concatentation is bugged though. Your orignal code should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function percentage(elementid)
{

    elementid = "markup_" + elementid;
    elementid = elementid + "_percentage";

document.getElementById(elementid).value = "a value";


}
```

I dont know why its working:

**-Could be concatenation problem , not allowed to use multiple " + " operators?**

**-Change variable name ?**

But it is working now, so thanks to all!